# Pandas: Find the left-most value in a pandas dataframe followed by all 1s

Tags: python, pandas, sum, row

I have the following dataset

```
data = {'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 
        '2012': [0, 1, 1, 1], 
        '2013': [0, 0, 1, 1], 
        '2014': [0, 0, 0, 1], 
        '2015': [0, 0, 1, 1], 
        '2016': [0, 0, 1, 0], 
        '2017': [1, 0, 1,1]}

df  = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

For each row I want to generate a new column -  `Baseline_Year` - which assumes the name of the column with all values to the right that are equal to 1. In case there is not column with all the values equal to 1, I would like the `Baseline_Year` to be equal to missing.

See the expected results

```
data = {'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 
        '2012': [0, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
        '2013': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
        '2014': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
        '2015': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1], 
        '2016': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 
        '2017': [1, 0, 1,1, 1],
        'Baseline_Year': [np.nan, np.nan, '2015','2017', '2012'],
       }

df_results  = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_results
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use a boolean mask and [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html):

```
# get year columns, identify rightmost 1s
m = (df.filter(regex=r'\d+')
       .loc[:, ::-1]
       .eq(1).cummin(axis=1)
       .loc[:, ::-1]
     )

df['Baseline_Year'] = m.idxmax(axis=1).where(m.any(axis=1))
```

Output:

```
  ID  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017 Baseline_Year
0  A     0     0     0     0     0     1          2017
1  B     1     0     0     0     0     0           NaN
2  C     1     1     0     1     1     1          2015
3  D     1     1     1     1     0     1          2017
```

If you want a minimum number of 1s on the right:

```
N = 2

df['Baseline_Year'] = m.idxmax(axis=1).where(m.sum(axis=1).ge(N))
```

Output:

```
  ID  2012  2013  2014  2015  2016  2017 Baseline_Year
0  A     0     0     0     0     0     1           NaN
1  B     1     0     0     0     0     0           NaN
2  C     1     1     0     1     1     1          2015
3  D     1     1     1     1     0     1           NaN
```

Intermediate `m`:

```
    2012   2013   2014   2015   2016   2017
0  False  False  False  False  False   True
1  False  False  False  False  False  False
2  False  False  False   True   True   True
3  False  False  False  False  False   True
```